# Angular 1.3.15 ngResource Delete

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

When I use Angular $resource.

I setting method like it.

```
return $resource('url', { id: "@id"}, {
  'delete': { method: 'DELETE}
});
```

But, I send request to server.

Request method isn't delete.

```
OPTIONS url HTTP/1.1
```

It's alway OPTIONS.

Please help me. How to change method delete?

Answer (score 0):

I was solve.

When I want to use http(delete method), browser will be send preflighted req.

My server is rails.

So I add somthing below.

**routes.rb**

```
match '*path', :controller => 'application', :actions => 'handle_options_request', :via => :options
```

It's will be to handle all options req.

**application_controller.rb**

```
def handle_options_request 
  head(:ok) if request.request_method == "OPTIONS"
end
```

Then it's response to client.